# Multilanguage WordPress blog; qTranslate-X vs WMPL

Tags: wordpress, wpml, qtranslate-x

I am looking for a wordpress plugin to make a self-hosting bilanguage personal blog (English & Turkish). Here are some main reqirements:

- Write and publish a single post in two languages **at the same time** and also have equivalent pages
- Automatic translate is required just for the blog environment not for my own posts
- Switch easily between two languages (e.g having en.blog.com & tr.blog.com)
- Easy to setup and use
- High speed

It seems that `qTranslate-X` and `WMPL` are two main available alternatives. What are pros and cons for each of them? Which one can be more suitable? Any personal experience would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Translate-X. Its really good Wordpress plugin. And its not automatic translation. Also you don't need the create new database.